# How do people greet each other when in different time zones?

Tags: time, greetings

How do people greet each other when they are in different time zones?

For example, suppose there is a phone call between two people: one is in Central European Time 1600 (say Germany, in the afternoon), and the other is in Eastern Standard Time (in the US, at 10am, the morning).

Do people greet each other with 'Good Monday/Tuesday/...? This doesn't completely solve the problem, but it's better than 'Good Morning/Afternoon/Evening'.

Comment: I was puzzled by your question, then I worked out that you mean 'How do you greet a person who is in a different time zone from yours?' I suppose, if you know what time it is where they are, you use the greeting appropriate for them.

Comment: I have never greeted anyone with "good Monday." In that style, I might say "good day" which doesn't exclude the night. We say "good night" on leaving at that time, not when greeting.

Comment: If in a different time zone, you are physically distant too, so I suggest "Hallo there!"

Comment: Most people start off with saying something for their own time zone, then realize that who they're talking to is in a different one, then say  '... or rather Good Morning where you are' and laugh because haha we live on a globe and one or both of you just woke up and are in pajamas. The more interesting question is what do astronauts say to each other and to people on Earth, and what do you say to them.

Comment: "Good morning/afternoon/whatever it is there!"

Comment: Saying "Good morning" (when it is evening where he is)  is not a problem.  A problem is: calling him when it is the middle of the night where he is.

Comment: This seems to be a question that has more to do with etiquette than with English language and usage. Either way, the answer is probably that there is no generally accepted convention for dealing with this matter. One might argue that it is courteous to use the greeting that is appropriate to the time at the location of the greeting's recipient, as that shows attentiveness to that person's circumstances. I doubt, though, that many people would be greatly offended if one used the greeting appropriate to one's own location.

Answer (score 2):

We usually say 'Good evening to India, good afternoon to Germany, good morning to America' or equivalent, or 'good morning, good afternoon, good evening, whichever time it is where you are', but it is still everytime as a half- or quarter-joke; there is simply no standard way to handle it, as it is too new a need to have made it into standard language.
Of course, you can avoid the issue by saying 'hello, how you are all doing' or some other expression that doesn't refer to the time of day.

It is very rare that different locations have different weekdays, and I haven't ever heard any reference to the weekday in the greeting anyway. So 'Good Monday', etc. is a no-no.

Comment: If the time zones are 12 hours apart, they have a different weekday 50% of the time. When 6 hours apart, 25% of the time.

Comment: @WeatherVane , but that's theoretical. Not many meetings happen at 9 pm / 3 am, because both times are rarely in the business hours. If you look at how the landmass of earth is distributed around the dateline (and not coincidentally), it is very rare to have business hour meetings across dates.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the dateline. The relevance of that is whether someone else's time is ahead or behind yours, and, it is not necessarily as business meeting. A younger person might call in the middle of the night so that a parent can talk in the day.

Comment: Working in the western US, with colleagues in Asia, they're almost always 1 day ahead of me when we have a meeting (5 pm here is 8 or 9 am the next day over there, depending on daylight savings).

Answer (score 0):

"Good day" of all responses seems the most rational, as every day has morning, noon and night.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the ELU. That might be so, but it would be good if you could provide an explanation or example or a reference that proves your point. One-sentence answers are discouraged on this site. See [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score -3):

How do people greet each other in different time zones?

Do people greet each other with good **M**onday/**T**uesday/...? They don't completely solve the problem **[Don't use commas for series of just two.]** but are better than good morning/afternoon/evening.

### Thanks.

*Good morning*, *Good afternoon*, and *Good evening* are not better. They're bad. No native English speaker ever says "Good Tuesday."

If you're not sure whether it's morning, afternoon, or night where the person you're talking with is, just say "Hello."

NOTE: Capitalize days of the week. They're proper nouns.

Comment: You have to know what time it is there anyway, to know which day of the week it is.

Comment: I’ve read this twice now and still don’t know what your answer is.